# String character difference in C#

Tags: c#, string, character, difference

We have two strings, `string first="abcdeabcde"` and `string second="cdefgcdefg"`.

What is the fastest/most typing-efficient way to come up with a third string which would contain only possible characters from first string, e.g. `string third="cdecde"`?

**More formal example:**

- First string contains characters from set `F={a,b,c,d,e}`
- Second string contains characters `S={c,d,e,f,g}`

I would like to know how can I quickly derive third string with characters from  set  `S\(S\F)= S intersection F`.

i.e.   string `second` containing characters in intersection of the strings.

**Second example:**

- string w="aaabbbccc"
- string z="bbbcccddd"
- expected result: string y="bbbccc" i.e. second string but with only characters b,c, which were in the first string

**Third example:**

- string a="ABCDABCDBABDBC" - random stuff from aplhabet {A,B,C,D}
- string b="CDEDECEDCDE" - random stuff from alphabet {C,D,E}
- final string f="CDDCDCD" - deleted all occurences of {E}

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the intersection of the two strings?  If so, there is a `String.Intersect` method that you could use.

Comment: More specifically, delete all characters from string not in intersection.

Comment: String.Except() produces the set difference of sequences. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.except%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I added that `S\(S\F)` is in fact `S` intersection `F`. I want characters in intersection to remain in final string, and all others be deleted.

Comment: So any character that does not exist in intersection of S and F, you want it removed from string `first` ?

Comment: probably a more realistic example would be helpful. why is "cdecde" better than "cde"?

Comment: Because that is intersection of two alphabets from these strings. "cdecde" is second string restricted on that intersected alphabet.

Comment: ah, I see - since it repeated in both the first and second string, I thought that was part of the requirement

Comment: would the result of your second example be different if the strings were `w = "abc"` and `z = "bbbcccddd"`?

Comment: It's not about concatenation, I added third example.

Comment: That conatenation is only there to form a string, the third exampe also works, didn't you read the explanation?

Comment: I don't see why it works. first = "ABCABCBACBACB". What if second string is like this: 
            string second= "BCDBBCDBBBCDBBBBCDBBBBBCD..." B, followed by CD, and number of B's is inreasing by 1. Then the resulting string should only contain B followed by C, 2 B's followed by C, etc...

Comment: string first = "ABCABCBACBABC";
            string second = "BCDBBCDBBBCDBBBBCDBBBBBCD"; output is: BCBCBCBBC which is clearly wrong

Comment: Yes, if you change that, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are looking for a short solution and performance is not an issue, you may want to try this:

```
var intersect = first.Intersect(second).ToList();
var result = new String(second.Where(c => intersect.Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string first = "abcdeabcde";
string second = "cdefgcdefg";

string intersection = String.Concat(first.Intersect(second));

string result = String.Concat(first.Where(c => intersection.Contains(c)));
Console.WriteLine(result); //output "cdecde"
```

**Explanation**:

The `Intersect` extension method returns an `IEnumerable<char>` that contains only the characters that exist in both strings, in order to convert it to a string, the `Concat` method concatenates all the members and returns the resulting string.

**Edit**

Now only characters that exist in the intersection should remain in string `first`

Comment: This only gives you the intersection of characters, the result should be `cdecde`. I thought using regexes but that would be slow.

Answer (score 0):

The `String.Intersect()` method should do exactly what you are looking for.  See more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intersect%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Example:

```
var string1 = "abcdefg";
var string2 = "cdekdjdfj";

var intersect = string1.Intersect(string2);
```

Comment: Technically, there isn't a `String.Intersect()` method. There's an `Enumerable.Intersect()` method that works on enumerations (and therefore works with a string as a character array). But the result ('intersect' in your example) is an `IEnumerable<Char>` instead of a `string`.